# Unknown graphics extension pdftex.def

Tags: graphics, pdftex, epstopdf

I am using latex  for my thesis. When I run the program and it's said *unknown graphics extensions*, .eps files. all eps files can be read when I convert DVI to Pdftextifying.
I am using `\usepackage{epstopdf}` this package also but it doesn't work too. I'm also using `\usepackage{graphicx}`.
Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by posting a minimal, but compilable, code example (MWE).

Answer (score 1):

The properly formulated question would specify what is "the program" that you run.

- if you run `latex`,  get a `dvi` file and then convert it to  `pdf`, it should work with `eps` files
- if you run `pdflatex`, you should either provide converted files from `eps` to `pdf`, or ask the package `epstopdf` to do it for you (by simply loading it).